# Classification of monotonic increasing functions.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a monotonically increasing function. $f$ can be $1-1$, in which case $f$ is strictly increasing. $f$ can be stair-step, in which case the jumps are at most countable. What are some other cases?

Comment: The jumps form an at most countable set for any montonic function.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: The following is rather advanced (which is why I pinged K. R. Murthy, in case he's interested), but of possible interest is my answer to [Points of differentiability of $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n : q_n < x} c_n$](https://mathoverflow.net/a/249794/15780) (which I might one day greatly expand, because at the time I had recently moved and the material I have on this topic was still scattered among different boxes) and [my 4 November 2000 sci.math post on the non-differentiability behavior of monotone functions](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/8vp1XK0-KNg/m/UOmRLJmd0xsJ).

Comment: Conversely to Kavi Rama Murthy's comment, every countable set is the set of discontinuities of a monotonic function.

Comment: $f$ could be a combination of continuous increase and jump increase. And the continuous increase might be like $x\mapsto \int_b^x g(t) dt $ (for a non-negative integrable $g$) or it might be singular, like the Cantor function ("devil's staircase"). In general a monotone increasing function $f$ can be uniquely (modulo an additive constant) decomposed as the sum of three terms of the type just described.

Comment: Regarding the comment by @John Dawkins see [Two questions on Lebesgue Decomposition of an increasing function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/432959/13130), and for the (more advanced) analogous version for measures see [Lebesgue decomposition $\nu =\nu_{cont}+\require{cancel} \cancel{\nu _{sing}}+\nu_{pp}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4110426/13130).